# YOLO v3 Linux VM OpenCV imtest

Tags: python, linux, opencv, yolo, darknet

I followed the instructions as given https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/ and have done everything. However, when I enter the final command to compile with OpenCV and execute *./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg* I get:

**L2 Norm: 371.992218
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Original.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Gray.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C1.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C2.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C3.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C4.png instead**

Comment: Seems like a bug, either in the tutorial, what you did or the software underneath. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. If you really want to turn this to a programming question, extract a [mcve] and provide that here.

Comment: So, you have installed OpenCV and followed the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Following message just indicates that predicted image will be saved as image for viewing, and it won't be able to show the predicted output using `imshow()` of OpenCV as you have not compiled `darknet` with `OpenCV`. **Note that this is not a error.**

```
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Original.png instead
```

From [this](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/) doc:

> By default, `darknet` uses `stb_image.h` for image loading. If you want
> more support for weird formats you can use `OpenCV` instead.

If you want to build `darknet` with `OpenCV` for any reason (note that it's not mandatory to have `OpenCV` to build and use `darknet`) then you need to **`install`** **`OpenCV`** first on your system.

Refer [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/#install-opencv-from-the-ubuntu-repository) to install `OpenCV` on ubuntu

After installation ensure:

> the directory containing `opencv.pc` is added to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
> environment variable

Otherwise you'll get error:

```
Package `OpenCV` was not found in the `pkg-config` search path
```

To ensure everything is find around installation and set up, check following commands:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

OR

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv4   #for opencv4
```

This will return version of OpenCV installed.

Ensure following commands return meaningful results:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

Next, change the 2nd line of the Makefile:

```
OPENCV=1
```

Then you re-**make** the project:

```
make
```